# Function Only Performs One While Loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am confused as why the function `function calculateGroceries()` only performs the first while loop `while(itemName != SENTINEL)` in the function. I tried to add parameters to not allow a blank answer to `itemName`. It is stays suck in the first while loop and doesn't continue to the next while loop  `while(isNaN(itemPrice) || itemPrice <= 0){`. The `const SENTINEL = "done';` is supposed to end the loop only when prompted for the `itemsName` as well. So far that works. I know its something small but can't figure it out.

```js
function calculateGroceries() {

  const SENTINEL = "done";

  let itemName = "none";
  let itemPrice = 0;
  let itemTotal = 0;
  let itemValues = 0;
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let total = document.getElementById("total");

  //while loop to not allow blank responses//
  while (itemName != SENTINEL) {
    itemName = prompt("Enter the item's name or " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");

    if (itemName == "") {
      alert("Field can't be blank. Enter item's name or " + SENTINEL + " to stop.")
    }
  }
  //while loop to not allow negative numbers or strings//
  while (isNaN(itemPrice) || itemPrice <= 0) {
    itemPrice = prompt("Enter the item's price.");
    itemPrice = parseFloat(itemPrice);

    if (itemPrice < 0) {
      alert("The number is less than 0. Enter a positive number")
    }
    if (isNaN(itemPrice)) {
      alert("You have to enter a number. Enter a number free of other characters.")
    }
    if (itemName != SENTINEL) {
      itemTotal += itemPrice;
      itemValues++;

      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = itemName

      list.appendChild(li);
      total.innerHTML = itemTotal;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> Grocery Shopping List </h1>
  <p>
    <form name="myForm">
      <!--prompts user for item name/price and calculates the total-->
      <button type="button" onclick="calculateGroceries();">Click here to enter the grocery list </button>
      <ul id="list"></ul>
      <div> Total: <span id="total"></span></div>
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I am sorry, I initially did not understand your question properly. I now have and here is how you can fix your problem:

**Problem:**
The problem is that the first while loop will continue to execute 'n' number of times until the user enters 'done'. But you want to also get the item price for each item that is entered, therefore, when Item Name is not empty i.e user entered a value you want to ask for the price immediately for that item, i.e because you want that price to be associated with that particular item.

Therefore, your price code block should also be located inside the first while loop, not outside the while loop. Check the else condition that I have added.

You can directly take and run this code, try to debug it and see if you can understand, in case you still have ant doubt, feel free to comment.

```
function calculateGroceries() {
  const SENTINEL = 'done';

  let itemName = 'none';
  let itemPrice = 0;
  let itemTotal = 0;
  let itemValues = 0;
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  let total = document.getElementById('total');

  //while loop to not allow blank responses//
  while (itemName !== SENTINEL) {
    itemName = prompt("Enter the item's name or " + SENTINEL + ' to stop.');

    if (itemName == '') {
      alert(
        "Field can't be blank. Enter item's name or " + SENTINEL + ' to stop.'
      );
    } else {
      //while loop to not allow negative numbers or strings//
    
      //you only want to ask for the price when the item name is not 'done' so we have this condition below
      if (itemName !== SENTINEL) 
        itemPrice = Number.parseFloat(prompt("Enter the item's price."));

      while (isNaN(itemPrice) || itemPrice <= 0) {
        if (itemPrice < 0) {
          alert('The number is less than 0. Enter a positive number');
        }
        if (isNaN(itemPrice)) {
          alert(
            'You have to enter a number. Enter a number free of other characters.'
          );
        }
        itemPrice = Number.parseFloat(prompt("Enter the item's price."));
      }

      itemTotal += itemPrice;
      itemValues++;

      let li;
      //only add item name to UI when it is not 'done'
      if (itemName !== SENTINEL) {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = itemName;
      }

      list.appendChild(li);
      total.innerHTML = itemTotal;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I tried your suggestion. It moves to the next loop but ends as soon as ````itemPrice```` is inputted. How do I get it to continue until the ````SENTINEL```` is typed?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I wasn't able to understand the question initially, but now I have. Please take a look at the above code, try it out in your app, it will work fine now and in case you have any doubts feel free to ask here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation. This helped me understand where I went wrong in my code